# How to insert and retrieve video from mongodb in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I new to mean stack. I want to upload video to mongodb and then I want to retrieve it.

> this is app.js file

```
  `const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Mongo URI
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://fawad:Fawad123@ds155243.mlab.com:55243/imageupload';

// Create mongo connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

// Init gfs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
  // Init stream
  gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
});

// Create storage engine
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: mongoURI,
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploads'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

// @route GET /
// @desc Loads form
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      res.render('index', { files: false });
    } else {
      files.map(file => {
        if (
          file.contentType === 'video/mp4' ||
          file.contentType === 'video/webm '
        ) {
          file.isVideo = true;
        } else {
          file.isVideo = false;
        }
      });
      res.render('index', { files: files });
    }
  });
});

// @route POST /upload
// @desc  Uploads file to DB
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  // res.json({ file: req.file });
  res.redirect('/');
});

// @route GET /files
// @desc  Display all files in JSON
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    // Check if files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No files exist'
      });
    }

    // Files exist
    return res.json(files);
  });
});

// @route GET /files/:filename
// @desc  Display single file object
app.get('/files/:filename', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if file
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No file exists'
      });
    }
    // File exists
    return res.json(file);
  });
});

// @route GET /image/:filename
// @desc Display Image
app.get('/video/:filename', (req, res) => {
  gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
    // Check if file
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        err: 'No file exists'
      });
    }

    // Check if image
    if (file.contentType === 'video/mp4' || file.contentType === 'video/webm') {
      // Read output to browser
      const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
      readstream.pipe(res);
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({
        err: 'Not an image'
      });
    }
  });
});

// @route DELETE /files/:id
// @desc  Delete file
app.delete('/files/:id', (req, res) => {
  gfs.remove({ _id: req.params.id, root: 'uploads' }, (err, gridStore) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({ err: err });
    }

    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

const port = 9000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
`
```

> index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    video {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Mongo File Uploads</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <h1 class="text-center display-4 my-4">Mongo File Uploads</h1>
        <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="custom-file mb-3">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="custom-file-input">
            <label for="file" class="custom-file-label">Choose File</label>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        </form>
        <hr>
        <% if(files){ %>
          <% files.forEach(function(file) { %>
            <div class="card card-body mb-3">
              <% if(file.isVideo) { %>
                <video src="video/<%= file.filename %>" alt="">
                <% } else { %>
                  <%= file.filename %>
                    <% } %>
                      <form method="POST" action="/files/<%= file._id %>?_method=DELETE">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-4">Delete</button>
                      </form>
            </div>
            <% }) %>
              <% } else { %>
                <p>No files to show</p>
                <% } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

this code work for image..when I used (file.contentType = image/png).
but for video it's not working.. is Image and video upload are same?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable). As It support multipart data. And for retrieve video you can use fs(file system)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't save media(image or video) in DB, you store it in some storage drive(locally or cloud) like s3 bucket, and then store its location url in your DB.
and this code might be helpful.

```
saveImage(urlPath, folderPath, multiple) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var timestamp = Date.now();
        var filepath = urlPath;
        var imageUrl;
        var ext = path.extname(filepath || '').split('.');
        var extension = ext[ext.length - 1];

        var tmp_path = filepath;
        imageUrl = folderPath + timestamp + '.' + extension;
        if (multiple != '' && multiple != undefined) { imageUrl = folderPath + timestamp + multiple + '.' + extension; }
        var target_path = __dirname + '/../' + imageUrl;//Change according to your location.
        console.log("target_path", target_path);
        mv(tmp_path, target_path, { mkdirp: true }, function (err) { })
        return resolve({ status: 1, url: imageUrl });
    })
}
```

Now, urlPath is your media path, foldarPath is path where you want to store your media and multiple is to give unique name.

you can call this method like this.

```
var multiple = Number(0) + Number(10);
                console.log("multiple", multiple);
                var saveImage = await 'YOUR_FILE_NAME'.saveImage(files.photo[0].path, 'public/Image/', multiple);
```

console.log(saveImage);

Answer (score 0):

```
<video src="video/<%= file.filename %>" controls alt="">
```

//Try adding the controls command in the video tag. It helps the video run.